# Can't modify *.plist LaunchDaemon on OS X

Tags: macos, nfs, launchd

I'm trying to (sudo) edit `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist`,  because I want to enable NFS shares as described [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/NFS#NFS_sharing_from_OS_X).

I am however unable to modify the specific `com.apple.nfsd.plist` file. SublimeText says it modified the file, but the changes disappear. Nano always mentions the 'Option is not permitted' and I am also unable to force vim to save the specific plist.

I tried modifying the `com.apple.nfsd.plist` the following ways:

- `sudo su`, and then `nano/vi com.apple.nfsd.plist`
- `sudo vim/nano/vi/subl` the specific file, and forcing :wq
- Turning off/restarting the nfsd service via `sudo stop nfsd`

Can't seem to add the extra `<string>-N</string>` in the .plist file. 
What am I overseeing?

Cheers

Comment: Are you using El Cap? If so then you have to turn off system integrity protection (denies you to do any change in specified locations; sudo can't help you neither)

Comment: You are absolutely right! El Capitan needs you to first disable System Integrity Protection (and then enable SIP again after the *.plist changes). Also saw this (too late) in the Troubleshooting wiki: [Kodi wiki][1]. Thanks for your help!


  [1]: http://kodi.wiki/view/NFS#Fresh_Installs_or_Upgrading_to_Mac_OS_X_10.11_El_Capitan